# Why can't I ng-include a sidenav?

Tags: html, angularjs, materialize, angularjs-ng-include

I created a sidenav using MaterializeCSS and its working fine. I also created a controller for it using angular. However when I try to include the sidenav in another html it doesn't work. I can only see the trigger button but when I click it nothing happens and there are no errors in the console.

Here is the sidenav:

```
    <div>

<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
  <li><div class="userView" ng-controller = "accountCtrl">
    <img class="background" src="img/wood.jpg">
    <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="img/profile-picture.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</span></a>
    <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">{{user.email}}</span></a>
  </div></li>

  <li><a><i class="material-icons">today</i>Today</a></li>
  <li><a><i class="material-icons">perm_identity</i>Account</a></li>
  <li><a><i class="material-icons">assignment</i>Projects</a></li>
  <li><a><i class="material-icons">perm_media</i>Gallery</a></li>

  <li><a class="subheader"></a></li>
  <li><a class="subheader"></a></li>

  <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
  <li><a><i class="material-icons">settings</i>Account Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- This is the button I can see when the file is included -->

<div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red button-collapse" 
  data-activates="slide-out"><i class="material-icons">label_outline</i></a>
</div>

</div>
```

And this is the ng-include in another html file.

```
 <div ng-include = "'partials/dashboard.html'" ng-controller = "dashboardCtrl"></div>
```

I can edit my post and show you the controller but I don't think its very important since i'm not really doing anything. I'm just initializing the sidenav.

Comment: What is the problem then? Does the sidenav not get included in the DOM or is it not linked to the controller?

Comment: It's not in the DOM. When I click on the button, the sidenav should appear but nothing happens. It is linked to the controller because I tested it out on its own (without including it anywhere) and it worked fine.

Comment: I Think there should be some class hiding the content

Comment: @r.j Where? If you're talking about the file that im including the sidenav in, then its completely empty. I only have the ng-include.

Comment: are you sure you have the right path to the dashboard.html?

Comment: @defaultcheckbox Yes, otherwise I wouldn't see the button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a scoping issue. The `ng-include` directive creates a new scope that prototypically inherits from of the enclosing scope. The `ng-controller` directive instantiates the controller on the parent of the new scope.

To have AngularJS build the html without creating a new scope, use a directive.

```
app.directive("dashboardComponent", function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
        controller: "dashboardCtrl"
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<dashboard-component></dashboard-component>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Wiki -- Understanding Scopes -- `ng-include`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-include)

Answer (score 0):

Does adding the href="#" make a difference?

```
<a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red button-collapse" 
  data-activates="slide-out"><i class="material-icons">label_outline</i></a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red button-collapse" 
  data-activates="slide-out"><i class="material-icons">label_outline</i></a>
```

Comment: Nope, no difference at all. It just redirects to /#